# PROLOG extracting words from string and putting them into List

Tags: prolog, nlp, extract, agent, dcg

I'm new to Prolog and I can't really think of any ways of dealing with this problem, basically i have a sentence for example:

```
phrase(det(a),np2(adj(large))).
```

From the sentence above I want to be able to extract in this case determiner (a) and adjective (large) and put them into a list so it looks like:

```
newList[a,large].
```

Comment: `newlist([Det,Adj]):-phrase_(det(Det),np2(adj(Adj))).`

Answer (score 3):

As you are working with phrase structure trees, which themselves represent grammar rules you might consider using DCGs for your task. First think about what your predicate should describe: a relation between a phrase structure tree and a list that consists of the words of that tree. You could name it pstree_words/2. Consider the minimal example below:

```
pstree_words(Phrase,List) :-
    phrase(Phrase,List).

phrase(det(A),np2(NP)) -->   % a phrase is
    det(A),                  % a det followed
    np2(NP).                 % by a np2

det(a) -->                   % a is a determiner
    [a].                     % hence in the list

np2(adj(A)) -->              % a np2 is
    adj(A).                  % an adj

adj(large) -->               % large is an adjective
    [large].                 % hence in the list
```

Note that the first goal of pstree_words/2 is not your structure phrase, but the built in predicate phrase/2 for handling DCGs. You can already use this to query for the words in the phrase structure tree:

```
   ?- pstree_words(phrase(det(a),np2(adj(large))),L).
L = [a,large]
```

If you want to add words you just need to add according rules. For example to add the determiner "the" you just add:

```
det(the) -->
    [the].
```

To add new phrase structures you just add new rules to phrase//2. However, if you try to query pstree_words the other way round, that is, to ask whether or not a sequence of words match a known phrase structure, it does not work. To remedy that you can alter the definition of pstree_words/2:

```
pstree_words(Phrase,List) :-
    is_phrase(Phrase),
    phrase(Phrase,List).

 is_phrase(phrase(_,_)).
```

The fact is_phrase/1 simply restricts `Phrase` to a two-place structure. If you add grammar rules to match e.g. 3-place structures for phrase you also add according facts for is_phrase/1: `is_phrase(phrase(_,_,_))`. With these alterations the predicate now works in the other direction too:

```
   ?- pstree_words(PST,[a,large]).
PST = phrase(det(a),np2(adj(large)))
```

Other possibly interesting uses: Which phrases with the words `[D,large]` are there?

```
   ?- pstree_words(PST,[D,large]).
D = a,
PST = phrase(det(a),np2(adj(large))) ? ;
D = the,
PST = phrase(det(the),np2(adj(large)))
```

Which phrases of the given structure are there?

```
   ?- pstree_words(phrase(det(D),np2(adj(A))),L).
A = large,
D = a,
L = [a,large] ? ;
A = large,
D = the,
L = [the,large] ? ;
```